# PHP-Imagick : Pattern image is loosing opacity

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagick

I am trying to tile/loop a simple [pattern-image](http://s10.postimg.org/zbkcas89x/pattern.png) over a `canvas-image`. Here is a relevant code-snippet.

```
$image = new \Imagick();
$image->newPseudoImage(700, 400, "canvas:black");
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$texture = new \Imagick(realpath('pattern.png'));
$image = $image->textureImage($texture);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image;
```

The `pattern-image` ( pattern.png ) is titling across the canvas just fine, but somehow it seems like transparency of pattern.png is messed up in the process. Here is the result I am getting.

[image: not good result]

---

Here is what the result image is expected to look like.

[image: expected result]

---

Just in case, here is a `var_dump` of `$texture->getImageProperties();`

```
array (size=8)
  'date:create' => string '2015-10-18T09:59:01+05:00' (length=25)
  'date:modify' => string '2015-02-08T20:53:20+05:00' (length=25)
  'png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig' => string '8' (length=1)
  'png:IHDR.bit_depth' => string '8' (length=1)
  'png:IHDR.color-type-orig' => string '0' (length=1)
  'png:IHDR.color_type' => string '0 (Grayscale)' (length=13)
  'png:IHDR.interlace_method' => string '0 (Not interlaced)' (length=18)
  'png:IHDR.width,height' => string '68, 34' (length=6)
```

---

**ENVIRONMENT** :

```
PHP Version 5.5.12
Wampserver2.5
Apache-2.4.9-
Imagick 3.1.2
mageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x64 2014-05-08
Windows 7 : 64 Bit.
```

---

**FOOTNOTES** : Although I have no clue where to start looking, I have started to check out the alpha channels. Also, other images are working fine so this could also be image-specific problem. Perhaps, that the image being an 8-bit ?? Do I need to remove transparency from the pattern.png ? If so how do I do it? Gimme your 2 cents :)

---

TRIED SO FAR THAT DID NOT WORK:

- `$image->setImageFormat("png24");`
- `$texture->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE);`

Comment: Could be a version difference, I have update the question with my environment.  Please share your environment and versions. Imagick, imagemagic, OS etc. Might help look for alternate functions.Thnx.

Comment: Looks like you got the latest of it all. What are my options here ?

Comment: thnx for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to feedback in comments section, it seems to be an issue with the version of imagick/imagmagick I have. Since I was not allowed to upgrade, here is an alternative I came up with, in case someone may find it useful.

```
$pattern = new Imagick(realpath('pattern.png')); // Create a new pattern object 
$pw = $pattern->getImageWidth();
$ph = $pattern->getImageHeight();

    $draw = new ImagickDraw(); // Create imagickdraw object 
    $draw->pushPattern('pattern', 0, 0, $pw, $ph);  // Create a pattern identifier 
    $draw->composite(Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0, $pw, $ph, $pattern); // Composite the pattern 
    $draw->popPattern(); // Close the pattern 
    $cw = 700;
    $ch = 400;

    $draw->push();
    $draw->setFillPatternURL('#pattern');   
    //$draw->setFillColor('yellow');
    $draw->rectangle(0, 0, $cw, $ch);
    $draw->pop();

$canvas = new Imagick(); // Create a new canvas object
$canvas->newImage($cw, $ch, "none");
$canvas->drawImage($draw); // Draw the ImagickDraw on to the canvas 
$canvas->setImageFormat('png'); // Set the format to PNG 
header("Content-Type: image/png"); // Output the image 
echo $canvas;
```